# Unable to create pluggable database on 19c using response file

Tags: multi-tenant, oracle-19c, containers

I am trying to create a pluggable database using a response file, but it is giving me the error below, indicating that one of the mandatory parameters is missing. Although I have checked it multiple times, I don't see that any missing mandatory parameter. Below is my response file which I am using.

```
 dbca -silent -createPluggableDatabase -responseFile /f01/app/oracle/dbca_pdb_creation.rsp
[INS-04008] Invalid combination of arguments passed from the command line. One or more mandatory dependent arguments are not passed for the argument: -create pluggable database
```

I am able to create the database when passing the required parameters directly in command line as below:

```
dbca -silent -createPluggableDatabase -sourceDB testcdb  -pdbName testpdb2 -createPDBFrom default  -pdbAdminUserName PDBADMIN  -pdbAdminPassword abcd1234
```

**Response file**

```
##############################################################################
##                                                                          ##
##                            DBCA response file                            ##
##                            ------------------                            ##
## Copyright(c) Oracle Corporation 1998,2019. All rights reserved.         ##
##                                                                          ##
## Specify values for the variables listed below to customize               ##
## your installation.                                                       ##
##                                                                          ##
## Each variable is associated with a comment. The comment                  ##
## can help to populate the variables with the appropriate                  ##
## values.                                                                  ##
##                                                                          ##
## IMPORTANT NOTE: This file contains plain text passwords and              ##
## should be secured to have read permission only by oracle user            ##
## or db administrator who owns this installation.                          ##
##############################################################################
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Do not change the following system-generated value. 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# GENERAL section is required for all types of database creations.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[GENERAL]

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name          : RESPONSEFILE_VERSION
# Datatype      : String
# Description   : Version of the database to create
# Valid values  : "12.1.0"
# Default value : None
# Mandatory     : Yes
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
responseFileVersion=/oracle/assistants/rspfmt_dbca_response_schema_v19.0.0

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name          : OPERATION_TYPE
# Datatype      : String
# Description   : Type of operation
# Valid values  : "createDatabase" \ "createTemplateFromDB" \ "createCloneTemplate" \ "deleteDatabase" \ "configureDatabase" \ "addInstance" (RAC-only) \ "deleteInstance" (RAC-only) \ "createPluggableDatabase" \ "unplugDatabase" \ "deletePluggableDatabase" \ "configurePluggableDatabase"
# Default value : None
# Mandatory     : Yes
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
OPERATION_TYPE = "createPluggableDatabase"

#-----------------------*** End of GENERAL section ***------------------------

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CREATEPLUGGABLEDATABASE section is used when OPERATION_TYPE is defined as "createPluggableDatabase". 
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[CREATEPLUGGABLEDATABASE]
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name          : SOURCEDB
# Datatype      : String
# Description   : The source database is the SID 
#     This database must be local and on the same ORACLE_HOME.
# Default value : none
# Mandatory     : YES
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SOURCEDB = "testcdb"

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name          : PDBNAME
# Datatype      : String
# Description   : The name of new pluggable database 
#     This pdb name must not be same as sourcedb name.
# Default value : none
# Mandatory     : YES
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
PDBNAME = "testpdb2"

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name          : CREATEASCLONE
# Datatype      : Boolean
# Description   : specify true or false for PDB to be create as Clone.
#               : When "true" is passed a new PDB GUID is generated for the plugged in PDB
# Default value : true
# Mandatory     : NO
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATEASCLONE = "TRUE"

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name          : CREATEPDBFROM
# Datatype      : String
# Description   : specify the source of pdb to be plugged
# Valid values  : DEFAULT | FILEARCHIVE | RMANBACKUP | USINGXML
# Default value : DEFAULT
# Mandatory     : NO
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATEPDBFROM = "DEFAULT"
 
 
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name          : PDBADMINUSERNAME
# Datatype      : String
# Description   : PDB Administrator user name
# Default value : None
# Mandatory     : Mandatory only when creating new DEFAULT PDB
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
PDBADMINUSERNAME = "PDBADMIN"

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name          : PDBADMINPASSWORD
# Datatype      : String
# Description   : PDB Administrator user password
# Default value : None
# Mandatory     : Mandatory only when creating new DEFAULT PDB
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
PDBADMINPASSWORD = "abcd1234"

#-----------------------*** End of createPluggableDatabase section ***------------------------
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You might be doubling up the createPluggableDatabase parameter - you've got it in the command line as well as in the .rsp file.

Try:

```
dbca -silent -responseFile /f01/app/oracle/dbca_pdb_creation.rsp
```

HTH

Comment: I have tried it before also and tried again but it does not work, reason is in 19c it has been made mandatory to provide the operation type before the -silent and without that it will give error. If I remove createPluggableDatabase from response file then also I am getting the same error as in my initial question.